# Datetime from Angular to asp .NET (boilerplate)

Tags: asp.net, angular, datetime

I cant' figure out how to fetch datetime (when an event takes place) from an Angular UI to my Microsoft SQL database in datetime format. That's the format in the DB: **0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000**, but honestly, I don't get that far.

```
    <div class="form-group row required">
      <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="eventTime">
        {{ "EventTime" | localize }}
      </label>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <input
          type="datetime-local"
          class="form-control"
          name="eventTime"
          id="eventTime"
          required
          [(ngModel)]="event.eventTime"
          #eventTimeModel="ngModel"
          #eventTimeEl
        />
        <abp-validation-summary
          [control]="eventTimeModel"
          [controlEl]="eventTimeEl"
        ></abp-validation-summary>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have that picked up by

```
        data = typeof data === 'object' ? data : {};
        data["categoryId"] = this.categoryId;
        data["category"] = this.category ? this.category.toJSON() : <any>undefined;
        data["name"] = this.name;
        data["description"] = this.description;
        data["location"] = this.location;
        data["phone"] = this.phone;
        data["email"] = this.email;
        data["notes"] = this.notes;
        data["limit"] = this.limit;
        data["creationTime"] = this.creationTime ? this.creationTime.toISOString() : <any>undefined;
        data["eventTime"] = this.eventTime ? this.eventTime.toISOString() : <any>undefined;
```

I have that end horribly with

```
ERROR TypeError: this.eventTime.toISOString is not a function
    at EventDto.push.KALY.EventDto.toJSON (main.js:12020)
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at EventServiceProxy.push.KALY.EventServiceProxy.create (main.js:7969)
    at CreateEventDialogComponent.push.aZhx.CreateEventDialogComponent.save (create-event-dialog.component.ts:53)
```

What should I do? To simplify things, I can assume that the time  zone doesn't change and is constant.

Edit:
Going for a proper date picker

```
<div class="form-group row required">
          <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="eventTime">
            {{ "EventTime" | localize }}
          </label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <input
            class="form-control"
            required
            [(ngModel)]="event.eventTime"
            name="eventTime"
            id="eventTime"
            [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dtPicker1" [owlDateTime]="dtPicker1">
            <owl-date-time #dtPicker1></owl-date-time>
```

AND

```
        data["eventTime"] = this.eventTime ? new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ') : <any>undefined; ///SUCCESS!!
```

did it for me.

Comment: what's the error you get? I see a stack trace, but no actual error.

Comment: Please add more details. It is very unclear from your question what your error is and also how it is occurring. You haven't included full methods, stack trace, etc. My guess would be that your issue is that you are calling `.toISOString()` on a string, not a Date. Input values are inherently strings and need to be converted to dates. I don't see you doing that in your code. Example can be seen [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ufb813?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: ERROR TypeError: this.eventTime.toISOString is not a function
    at EventDto.push.KALY.EventDto.toJSON (main.js:12020)
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at EventServiceProxy.push.KALY.EventServiceProxy.create (main.js:7969)
    at CreateEventDialogComponent.push.aZhx.CreateEvent

Sorry, it cut off

Comment: Please "Edit" your original post (vs. adding a comment).  Please copy/paste 1) the full traceback, with error text, *AND* 2) the JSON message text.  But you've told us enough to verify that the problem is that your field is *NOT* being recognized as a "Date" object.  My guess? The JSON is probably coming across as a "number" or a "string".  Again - PLEASE SHOW US THE JSON!

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't understand what you meant by showing the JSON :( I tried to log the value, at least, to understand what comes out of that date picker - never got it to show anything other that undefined, so obviously I was doing that wrong, too.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, date/time values are stored in the database as an integral number with respect to an [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (e.g. #/seconds since Jan 1, 1970).  *NOT* a value like "MM/dd/yyyy", and certainly *NOT* with respect to any "time zone". The value is *INDEPENDENT* of any time zone.  In your case, the number (the date/time value) you're reading into Angular happens to be "0".

Q: How would you like your program to behave if it encounters a date/time value of "0"?  Please clarify "expected behavior".

Q: What is the actual error?  You included the stack trace ... but not the error message. Please add this to your post.

Q: What does the input JSON look like?  Could you copy/paste the relevant JSON into your post?

Please update your post, so we can give you a better informed answer :)

Comment: Datetime value 0 shouldn't happen, it's either null or the date. The issue is indeed with the toISOString() method, but I don't know how to get from the string provided to the Date object in this context. Or whether I should approach the issue differently in general.

Comment: I finally got the console log working for this and it turns out the datetime-local is returning undefined.


 sConsole(event) {
  var data = document.getElementById("eventTime");
  console.log(data["eventTime"])}

But I don't know why.

Comment: "Datetime value 0 shouldn't happen, it's either null or the date".  This is NOT necessarily true!  Frequently (especially if you're developing your schema with Entity Framework, instead of "raw SQL"), the column will default to "0" (*NOT* "null") if no date value is provided during "insert".  But you need to look at the actual JSON in the message ("data").  Anything else is "pure speculation".  We're waiting for you to update your post...

Comment: Got it done!         

data["eventTime"] = this.eventTime ? new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ') : <any>undefined; 

was a success coupled with [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dtPicker1" [owlDateTime]="dtPicker1"> did it for me. Thank you! If I could only figure out angular component composition, too :D

Answer (score 0):

Going for a proper date picker

```
<div class="form-group row required">
          <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="eventTime">
            {{ "EventTime" | localize }}
          </label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <input
            class="form-control"
            required
            [(ngModel)]="event.eventTime"
            name="eventTime"
            id="eventTime"
            [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dtPicker1" [owlDateTime]="dtPicker1">
            <owl-date-time #dtPicker1></owl-date-time>
```

AND

```
        data["eventTime"] = this.eventTime ? new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ') : <any>undefined; ///SUCCESS!!
```

did it for me.

Comment: All well and good.  BUT.... 1) If you did a "select" in your DB, you might see *EITHER* "null" *OR* "0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000", depending on how the column was defined.  Entity Framework typically sets a default of "0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000", or epoch value "0". 2) The thing that *MATTERS* is the JSON for "this.eventTime", which you failed to show us.  3) Anyway - glad you figured out how to get the behavior you were looking for :)